# Can I manage content structure with a rich text editor?

Tags: tinymce, rich-text-editor

I'm developing a CMS, and I'm trying to figure out which rich text editor (if any) I want to use.

The content is stored in a structured form on the server. Let's call it the "canonical form". It is not a simple HTML or markdown page, but a multi-part structure where each part is stored as individual records in the database.

The server reads the canonical form and sends it to the client. The client transforms the canonical form into HTML. I now want to let the user edit the content, and save it back to the server in canonical form.

I'm not sure a rich text editor will do the trick. It seems most RTE's give you HTML, leaving it up to you to parse the HTML and save it. The problem is that the conversion of canonical to HTML is one-way. The canonical form is different enough from HTML that the transformation can't be readily reversed.

So I need some kind of intimate interaction with the editor. I need to track all the things the editor does (select, copy, paste, drag-n-drop, splitting blocks, merging blocks, etc.) as the editor is doing it, so that I can maintain the canonical form in parallel with the displayed HTML.

Is there anything out there that will do this? I'm looking at TinyMCE, CKEditor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably going to need logic that converts content into canonical form on an editor `get` operation, and the inverse on an editor `set` operation.

[Textbox.io](http://docs.ephox.com/display/tbio/Filtering+content) supports the idea of filters for content. You could possibly tie this in with something like [Markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) to get your canonical format.